# Netlogo: Turtle checking if it can move into a valid target

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, netlogo, move, patch

I am trying to simulate a neighbourhood visiting local businesses. There are two breeds of patches (home and businesses) and turtles (people and owners). The plan is to have people be able to visit a shop if an owner is on the business patch, and considered closed otherwise.

A day is split into three ticks: morning, afternoon, and evening. All shops are often in the morning and the afternoon, but a random number of owners go home in the evening. If shops are unavailable, owners will just go home.

After a while of running, I get the error **MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead.** Pointing to the "ifelse" section of the evening-move command.

Thank you for the help!

```
to go
  morning-move ;Morning movement (First shopping phase)
  tick

  afternoon-move ;Afternoon movement (Second shopping phase)

  tick

  evening-move ;Evening movement (Return home)

  tick

end

to morning-move
  ask owners [move-to work-xy] ;make owners open their businesses
    ask people [ifelse any? open-busi-patches with [any? owners-here and count people-here < MaxCapacity] ;This checks if there are open businesses
    [ask people [move-to one-of open-busi-patches with [any? owners-here and count people-here < MaxCapacity]]] ;move people to businesses under capacity
    [ask people [move-to home-xy]]]
  ask open-busi-patches [set OpsProfit OpsProfit + count people-here] ;cumulative count of patrons
end

to afternoon-move
  ask people [ifelse any? open-busi-patches with [count owners-here > 0 and count people-here < MaxCapacity] ;This checks 
    [ask people [move-to one-of open-busi-patches with [any? owners-here and count people-here < MaxCapacity]]] ;move people to businesses under capacity
    [ask people [move-to home-xy]]]
  ask open-busi-patches [set OpsProfit OpsProfit + count people-here] ;cumulative count of patrons
end

to evening-move
  ask n-of random count owners owners [move-to home-xy] ;This choses a random number of owners to stay open in the evening.
  ask people [ifelse any? open-busi-patches with [any? owners-here and count people-here < MaxCapacity] ;This checks 
    [ask people [move-to one-of open-busi-patches with [any? owners-here and count people-here < MaxCapacity]]] ;move people to businesses under capacity
    [ask people [move-to home-xy]]]
  ask open-busi-patches [set OpsProfit OpsProfit + count people-here] ;cumulative count of patrons
end
```

Comment: The evening move and the morning move are identical except choosing a random number of people.  So maybe a random number of people can be zero?  That would produce the error, wouldn't it?  Maybe you need something that makes sure the minimum random number of people is 1?  Also, why is the ifelse for afternoon move different from the other two?

Comment: I was hoping that if there were no shops available or open, they would return home. Ideally - if there are no available shops, the people return home without attempting to enter a business. However, I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with netlogo to have a good solution for this. The long term application for this code is to investigate how a disease transfers through the neighbourhood. So if an owner is sick and not working, the people would ignore the shop. The afternoon-move being different is lack of due-diligence, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Ok, I don't understand why the ifelse doesn't handle having 0 shops open - my naive suggestion was to make the minimum number of shops open be 1 - and that doesn't help you.  Hopefully someone else will have a real suggestion!  How does `open-busi-patches` become true or false?  It seems like the move to is using the same exact constraint as the ifelse condition so it should only fail if the ifelse has open business and then when the move to is executed there aren't any.

Comment: I appreciate it, @JerryJeremiah! Switching from `open-busi-patches` to `closed-busi-patches` will be if the patch is able to get enough patrons by 90 ticks (to simulate a month's worth of operational cost). I considered setting the patches to `closed-busi-patches` for the evenings, but I decided to work on the people movement first. At least, I like to think I can change the conditions in an upcoming code version without breaking the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the code that is giving you the error (reformatted)

```
to afternoon-move
  ask people
  [ ifelse any? open-busi-patches with [count owners-here > 0 and count people-here < MaxCapacity ]
    [ ask people ;;;; THIS LINE
      [ move-to one-of open-busi-patches with [any? owners-here and count people-here < MaxCapacity]
      ]
    ]
    [ ask people
      [ move-to home-xy]
    ]
  ]
  ask open-busi-patches [set OpsProfit OpsProfit + count people-here]
end
```

The basic problem is that the line I have marked is actually moving people and using up the open businesses. So the first condition tests whether there are businesses with space initially and it never gets retested.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @JenB! I added another ifelse statement where you pointed, and I haven't had an error message in a very long run!